# Task Queue Java API

Tags: java, google-app-engine, queue, task

Hi when i started to work on Task queue concept i got struck on this line

```
 queue.add(
  DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService().getCurrentTransaction(),
  TaskOptions().url("/path/to/my/worker"));
```

What will DatastoreServiceFactory do... How to redirect this page to another servlet.... in the url i gave 
 .url("/myservlet") but it doesn't redirected to servlet Please say what should given in .url.Help me.

Regards,
sharun

Comment: This is your fifth(!) question with this title.

Comment: But Still i didnt get answer.... I'm a beginner i'm having many doubts

Comment: where will i clarify my doubts is it wrong to ask my doubts?

Answer (score 0):

in your example, the `DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService().getCurrentTransaction()` argument is used to attach a task to the current datastore transaction. if you provide that argument, the task will be added if and only if the datastore transaction commits.

in your case, the task probably isn't executing your servlet because you don't commit the datastore transaction. remove the transaction parameter entirely and just try this instead:

```
queue.add(TaskOptions().url("/path/to/my/worker"));
```